# Redis transaction -- pass result of one command to another

Tags: caching, transactions, redis

Is there a way in Redis to execute a series of commands atomically passing the result of the previous command into the subsequent command?

I know this can be done by executing a Lua script, but is there a top-level feature that supports this?

Comment: At the moment, only Lua